# How to insert a div for every nth object in laravel

Tags: css, collections, laravel-5

I have a foreach loop where I need to insert a div every nth object.

```
 @if(count($articles))

    @foreach($articles as $article)

        @if(this is the nth object)
            <div class="row margin-b-2">
        @endif
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a style="background-color: {{ $article->category->color }}" href="{{ route('category', ['category_slug' => $article->category->slug])  }}">{{ $article->category->title }}</a>
            </div>

        @if(this is the nth object)
           </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
 @endif
```

this is the bare bones of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the modulus division operator. If for example you wanted it after every 9 articles:

```
<?php $counter = 1; ?>

@if(count($articles))

    @foreach($articles as $article)

        @if($counter % 9 == 0)
             <div class="row margin-b-2">
        @endif
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a style="background-color: {{ $article->category->color }}" href="{{ route('category', ['category_slug' => $article->category->slug])  }}">{{ $article->category->title }}</a>
        </div>

        @if($counter % 9 == 0)
           </div>
        @endif
   <?php $counter++; ?>
   @endforeach
 @endif
```

How this works: Modulus division returns the remainder. The remainder is always equal to 0 when you are at an even multiple.

Comment: Thanks, that was the method I was trying to use but was struggling to initialise a variable in blade.