# Breaking foreach loop to the limit of three loops

Tags: php, laravel

I am looping through database and inserting a new div for every 5th div following this:

[How to insert a div for every nth object in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158211/how-to-insert-a-div-for-every-nth-object-in-laravel)

How can I add a break so it only limits a new div three times of every 5th div?

```
<?php $counter = 1;?>

@if(count($images))

@foreach($images as $image)

    <div class="grid-item">
      <a href='{{route('specImage', $image->id)}}'>
    </div>  

    @if($counter % 5 == 0) 

     <div class="grid-item">             
       <div class="new-div">           
    </div>  

    @endif

<?php $counter++; ?>

@endforeach

@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work for you :

```
  @if (count($images))
    @foreach ($images as $counter => $image)
        @php $counter++; @endphp
        <div class="grid-item">
            <a href='{{route('specImage', $image->id)}}'>
        </div>
        @if ($counter % 5 == 0 && $counter <= 15)
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="new-div">           
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
  @endif
```

Comment: This would only show objects along until the three loops? I wanted to show all 63 objects while inserting a new div only to the first three times. This would only show 18 including the new div.